# Insert non-duplicate data into a table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a non duplicate records into a table but which doing so I am unable to insert it it gives me (0 row(s) affected). And actually the table itself is empty and I am insert new records. To ignore inserting duplicate records I am doing it in the query which I have added below.

```
Insert Into OrderDetails (CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderID, OrderDate, ProductID, ProductName, Unit, Price)
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, i.OrderID, i.OrderDate, p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.Unit, p.Price
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN items i ON c.CustomerID=i.CustomerID
INNER JOIN itemsDetails id ON i.OrderID = id.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products P ON p.ProductID = id.ProductID
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON c.CustomerID = od.CustomerID
where c.CustomerID != od.CustomerID
```

Am I Inserting correctly?

Comment: how many rows does your `select` statement alone return? You are `inserting` into `orderdetails` and you say the table is empty. The table is also in the `join` clause. Hence you will not get any rows from `select`. I suggest you remove `orderdetails` from `join`.

Comment: i think the syntax is: INSERT INTO tablename(...) VALUES

Comment: @LuckAss, nope, not when INSERT ... SELECT.

Comment: try the select statement in your DB on it's own and check if any values are returned

Comment: Tag the dbms product you're using.

Comment: @LuckAss it shows 0 records as My Orderdetails is empty and I am inserting fresh records to that table.

Comment: That WHERE clause looks suspicious...

Comment: that's the problem, if you join without any records, there are no records ;)

Comment: you need to change it, so you get records to insert ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Insert Into OrderDetails (CustomerID, CustomerName, OrderID, OrderDate, ProductID, ProductName, Unit, Price)
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, i.OrderID, i.OrderDate, p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.Unit, p.Price
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN items i ON c.CustomerID=i.CustomerID
INNER JOIN itemsDetails id ON i.OrderID = id.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products P ON p.ProductID = id.ProductID
where c.CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT customerid FROM orderdetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the two last rows of your statement:

```
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON c.CustomerID = od.CustomerID
where c.CustomerID != od.CustomerID
```

In the inner join, you require the CustomerID be the same.
In the where clause, you require the CustomerID to be different.

Remove the inner join of the table OrderDetails.